# What is the value of the following expression ? I = 1; I = (I<<= 1 % 2) (a) 2 (b) 1 (c) 0 (d) syntax error

Tags: c

What is the value of the following expression ?

```
      I = 1;
      I = (I<<= 1 % 2)
```

Choose from the following:

```
(a) 2     
(b) 1      
(c) 0      
(d) syntax error
```

Comment: Have you tried running it?

Comment: `1%2` == `1` and `I <<= 1` == `I = I << 1` == `I = 1 << 1` = `I = 2` so `2` is answer

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Or a syntax error if `I` isn't an integer type or isn't declared...

Comment: I'm in a good mood.. http://ideone.com/nJlKTA

Comment: In this case running it does no real good -- since it has undefined behavior, anything from differences in compilers to compiler flags to phases of the moon could cause different results.

Comment: Is says "in the following expression", but the code given has more than one expression.

Comment: @Mysticial yes because syntax error is an option.

Comment: [C Sequence Points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azk8zbxd.aspx)

Comment: or (e) Remove this code from your application and fire the original author

Comment: @JerryCoffin as of the C99 std phases of the moon are required not to influence the output of any valid C program

Comment: @aaronman: Yes, but "undefined behavior" means it's *not* a valid C program, so phases of the moon can still affect the behavior.

Answer (score 6):

In the first expression, the value is obviously `1`.

In the second expression you have undefined behavior, because `I` is modified twice without an intervening [**sequence point**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

Comment: This gives me the impression that the question might be from an interview or academia, but the one who wrote the question wasn't actually qualified to do that ;-D

Comment: @NikosC. you are probably correct because `undefined behavior` is not an option in answer so question is invalid. I answer based on option (*that's why in comment*)

Comment: @Jim: Many think that, but they're wrong. The assignment operator does *not* create a sequence point. C99, §6.5/2: "Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value  modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression."

Comment: @JimBalter: The result of `(I<<= 1 % 2)` must be evaluated before the result can be assigned to `I`, but the side effect of modifying `I` doesn't have to be. `I` is modified twice with no intervening sequence point, therefore the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @KeithThompson: While that certainly *seems* a lot more reasonable, even that isn't entirely accurate. For example, since the value of `I` before the expression is known, the compiler could pre-compute arbitrary parts of this at compile time, so the apparent dependency disappears completely.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Sure, but that doesn't affect the undefinedness of the behavior.